# Get title from sibling control

Tags: sapui5

I have an SAPUI5 List control in OPA5 tests. This control has sap.m.Dialog as parent control.

Earlier, I use to get the title for parent control using: `getParent.getTitle()`, and this was working fine.

Now, I have a requirement to get title of another child (sap.m.Bar) control of sap.m.Dialog.
Relation between these control is somewhat like this:

[image]

I want to fetch title from sap.m.Bar, and use it in sap.m.List. In short, something like this:

[image]

So I need title **"ac"** here in my opa5 tests. Any idea how can I do that? What should I use in sap.m.List control to fetch title from its sibling?

Comment: can you try the following : fetch the list. From list, get Dialog. From dialog, get its content. As per diagram, content[0] of dialog is the bar you need. `var oDialog = oList.getParent(); var oBar = oDialog.getContent()[0];` From this bar, get the title, using getContentLeft/getContentMiddle/getContentRight.

Comment: it worked, thanks! I will post it as an answer so that it will be helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Rahul in the comment, I did traversal from child->parent->another child, and it worked!

```
var oDialog = oList.getParent();
var oBar = oDialog.getContent()[0].getTitle().getText();
```